# compile warnings on function with socket C

Tags: c, sockets, function

This is my program:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Uso: ./server <numero porta>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int sockd, newsockd, LunghezzaClient;
    int NumPorta = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr; /* indirizzo del server e del client */
    int rc, fd;
    off_t offset = 0;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    char filename[1024] = {};
    size_t fsize;

    if((sockd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("Errore creazione socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); /* bzero scrive dei null bytes dove specificato per la lunghezza specificata */
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /* la famiglia dei protocolli */
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(NumPorta); /* porta htons converte nell'ordine dei byte di rete */
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* dato che è un server bisogna associargli l'indirizzo della macchina su cui sta girando */

    if(bind(sockd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        perror("Errore di bind\n");
        onexit(NULL, sockd, NULL, 1);
    }

    if(listen(sockd, 5) < 0){
            perror("Errore nella funzione listen");
            onexit(NULL, sockd, NULL, 1);
    }
    LunghezzaClient = sizeof(cli_addr);
    signal (SIGINT, ( void *)sig_handler); 
    while(1){
        if((newsockd = accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t *) &LunghezzaClient)) < 0){
            perror("Errore nella connessione\n");
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, NULL, 2);
        }

        /* get the file name from the client */
        if((rc = recv(newsockd, filename, sizeof(filename), 0)) < 0){
            perror("Errore nella ricezione del nome del file");
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, NULL, 2);
        }

        /* Terminiamo il nome del file con NULL e se ultimo carattere è \n o \r lo cambiamo con \0*/
        filename[rc] = '\0';
        if (filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\n')
            filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';
        if (filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\r')
            filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';

        /* inet_ntoa converte un hostname in un ip decimale puntato */
        fprintf(stderr, "Ricevuta richiesta di inviare il file '%s' dall' indirizzo %s\n", filename, inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

        /* open the file to be sent */
        fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Impossibile aprire '%s': %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, NULL, 2);
        }

        /* get the size of the file to be sent */
        if(fstat(fd, &stat_buf) < 0){
            perror("Errore fstat");
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, fd, 3);
        }
        fsize = stat_buf.st_size;
        if(send(newsockd, &fsize, sizeof(fsize), 0) < 0){
            perror("Errore durante l'invio della grandezza del file\n");
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, fd, 3);
        }
        /* copy file using sendfile */
        offset = 0;
        rc = sendfile(newsockd, fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
        if (rc == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore durante l'invio di: '%s'\n", strerror(errno));
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, fd, 3);
        }
        if (rc != fsize) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Trasferimento incompleto: %d di %d bytes\n", rc, (int)stat_buf.st_size);
            onexit(newsockd, sockd, fd, 3);
        }

        onexit(newsockd, NULL, fd, 4);
    }
    close(sockd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But when i try to compile it with `gcc -Wall -O3 -o program myprogram.c` i got **a lot** of warnings due too some mistakes into `onexit` function. Here's the warnings i got:

```
server-iterativo.c: In function ‘main’:
server-iterativo.c:51:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘onexit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
server-iterativo.c:56:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘onexit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
server-iterativo.c:92:7: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘onexit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
server-iterativo.c:97:7: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘onexit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
server-iterativo.c:104:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘onexit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
server-iterativo.c:108:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘onexit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
server-iterativo.c:111:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘onexit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
server-iterativo.c:111:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘onexit’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
server-iterativo.c:23:6: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
server-iterativo.c: In function ‘onexit’:
server-iterativo.c:131:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘close’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:354:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
server-iterativo.c:136:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘close’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:354:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
```

I cannot understand why i got this errors :(

Comment: Looks like you're confusing fopen/fclose with open/close.

Comment: The warnings are about calling `onexit`, so maybe you should show _how_ you call it? Also, almost all the warnings are about you passing wrong parameters to that function. Just go over the lines referenced in the warning messages and check how you call the function.

Comment: Also, calling your function `onexit` might be a bad naming choice, as it's easily confused with the system library `on_exit` function.

Comment: sorry you're right :( i've updated my code with the main!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message looks clear enough:

In the code that you removed, in `main`, you call your function `onexit` that expects its parameter 1 to be an `int` with a pointer. You should feed an `int`!

---

Once again. *You* defined your own function `onexit` as follows:

```
void onexit(int c, int s, FILE *fp, int flag);
```

*You* choose that it wants as parameter 1 an `int`. Then, when you call it as follows:

```
onexit(NULL, sockd, NULL, 1);
```

*You* give it `NULL` as parameter 1, which is a pointer, not an `int`.

Hence, the compiler warns *you* that it had to *make an integer from a pointer*.

Comment: Note there is a second type of error here --- he's calling close on `int`s

Comment: and how can i substitute "null" into the function if i have no args?

Comment: @polslinux You said your function wants, an `int`. Give it an `int`! `0` is an `int` for example, just as `1`, `-1`, or `42` are!

Answer (score 1):

BTW The code fragment below will do nasty things if rc happens to be zero:

```
filename[rc] = '\0';
if (filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\n')
    filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';
if (filename[strlen(filename)-1] == '\r')
    filename[strlen(filename)-1] = '\0';
```

Better check rc first:

```
if (rc > 0 && filename[rc-1] == '\n') filename[--rc] = 0;
if (rc > 0 && filename[rc-1] == '\r') filename[--rc] = 0;
```

Avoiding 2-4 calls to strlen() will save you some cycles, too.

And to avoid a buffer overrun (rc could be equal to sizeof filename), you could use

```
if((rc = recv(newsockd, filename, sizeof filename -1, 0)) < 0){...}
```